# Radial function and integral

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis

Let $\Phi:(0,\infty)\rightarrow(0,\infty)$ be an increasing function and $\rho:(0,\infty)\rightarrow(0,\infty)$ is a function satisying the property
$$
\frac{1}{C}\leq\frac{\rho(s)}{\rho(r)}\leq C ~~\text{ for }~~\frac{1}{2}\leq\frac{s}{r}\leq2,~~~~~~~~~(\ast)
$$
where $C>0$ is independent of $r,s>0$.

The article which i read now, the author states that: from $(\ast)$ property of $\rho$ and increasingness of $\Phi$ it follows that
$$
\int_{|x-y|\geq r}\Phi\left(\frac{\rho(|x-y|)}{\lambda|x-y|^n}\right)dy\leq C\int_{r}^{\infty}\Phi\left(\frac{\rho(t)}{\lambda t^n}\right)t^{n-1}dt,
$$
where $C>0$ is independent of $\lambda>0$ and $x\in\mathbb{R^n}$.

My questions are:

Why do we need these properties to get this inequality ?

Without using these properties couldn't we get this inequality as a direct result of the well-known fact
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R^n}}f(|x|)dx=\omega_{n-1}\int_{0}^{\infty}f(r)r^{n-1}dr,
$$ 
where $\omega_{n-1}$ denotes the surface area of the $(n-1)$-sphere of radius $1$.